# How would I go about jogging part of my commute back to home?

Tags: jogging

I work at 8.5 km from home. I often take my bicycle (about 30-35 minutes), but when the weather itself looks like it would rain, I take the bus or get a lift from my parents.

The bus on the way home stops about halfway, 4 km from my home, which I can and have walked before. the path goes via a pretty busy road, but it has a sidewalk for about 90% of the way, and a cycling lane for the remaining 10%, and every busy intersection I need to cross has traffic lights. the road itself is mostly level, although the last KM has a slight decline. I've made a google maps that shows the path (not quite to my house, I'm not that stupid): https://www.google.be/maps/dir/51.1571561,4.4154346/51.146091,4.4465674/@51.1521886,4.4352632,15z/data=!4m9!4m8!1m5!3m4!1m2!1d4.44544!2d51.15539!3s0x47c3f0982c5624f9:0x31820bda1d367bae!1m0!3e2?hl=en

My bus stops at the hospital. I can make a transfer there to a bus that follows the same trajectory, but depending on the time I arrive at the hospital, it's often just as fast to walk. However, I'm thinking jogging might even be a feasible alternative, given the relatively short distance and acceptable road conditions. What I'm wondering about is if I would need any special equipment or training to jog this part. Do I need special shoes and clothes or can I do this in my normal working clothes (button-down shirt, jeans or other comfortable pants, pretty casual shoes)? Would I need any particular training or excercise before I do this (I don't have an amazing or even great condition, but I can do multi hour bicycle rides of 40-50 km)? Is it sane to start with a 4 km jog right away or should I start with taking the bus and going from somewhere partway?

Comment: Start with the jog. If you make it cool, if not just walk part of it. Look at Galloway run/walk for examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR Don't start with 4K right away; Don't run in your work clothes.

I started running about a year ago and jog part of my commute on some days, so I guess my experience might be helpful.

1. Get started on something you can control nicely. Although you can ride a bike for quite some distance, running is just different. So I'd recommend running around the block until you get a feeling what distance you can cover and at what speed.
2. Get started slowly. Start with something like 30min. Jogg as much as you can, walk the rest. Try reducing the time you are walking until it is zero.
3. Get proper clothing, especially shoes. Of course you can do your first trips in what ever feels comfortable. But once you start to sweat, anything suitable for work will become uncomfortable. Shoes will get completely soaked from sweat alone. So as soon as you get sure that you will continue running/jogging for some time. Get some micro fibre shirt, running pants and running shoes. Go to a specialized shop for the shoes.
4. For the actual running home part: Bring your running clothes to work. After work, change clothes. You can take your working cloths home on the next day.
5. Makes sure you take as little weight as possible, because anything bouncing up and down in your pockets, becomes really annoying really fast. Also make sure it is water proof When I plan to run home I take a little zipper bag for:

   - My key, only the key(s) I absolutely need, no keychain
   - credit card or a 10Euro note (it feels better to have some money, just in case)
   - bus ticket
6. Whatever you carry make sure it is close and tight to your body. Again you don't want it bouncing around. I got myself an [SPI belt](http://www.spibelt.com/) for this.

Answer (score 1):

Nate: Here is what I would do.
Bring your running clothes to work along with your running shoes. On the days you plan on running home you can change into your running cloth before you leave and then run any distance or section that you want. If you are already riding 40-50km you should be able to run/walk 4k. As you get more used to running this distance you can increase your pace and change your route around a little.

If you need to bring cloths home then you could get a running backpack which would allow you to carry some limited items. You want to get a back that sits high on your back and has a strap across your chest and your waist.

For shoes you should go to a running store and have them fitted.